# Jenkins reads double quotes as single quote causing ambiguous redirect error

Tags: bash, jenkins

I'm creating my first job in Jenkins and for the Execute shell command I have the following:

```
C:/project/script.sh "Execute script" flag1 flag2 - -
```

The build fails. When I look at the console output I see

```
+ C:/projects/script.sh 'Executing build script' flag1 flag2 - -
C:/projects/script.sh: line 29: $LOGFILE: ambiguous redirect
```

I believe the ambiguous redirect is because Jenkins is converting the double quotes into single quotes. The original command works fine outside jenkins.

Is there a way to get Jenkins to use double quotes, as the script expects?
I'm using jenkins-1.641 on Windows server 2012

script.sh looks like this:

```
line 20 #include file
line 21 if [ "$parameterFile" != "" ] 
line 22   then source $parameterFile ; else source $CURRENT_DIR/scripts/parameter.sh
line 23 fi 
line 24 source $SCRIPT_FOLDER/functions.sh
line 25 source $SCRIPT_FOLDER/mailfunctions.sh
line 26
line 27 #file to save the log
line 28 export LOGFILE=$(pwd)/${PROJECT_NAME}_build_$(date "+%Y-%m-%d_%H%M%S").log
line 29 echo > $LOGFILE
line 30 echo > $LOG_FILE_REPO
```

Comment: Add `script.sh`, your OS/distribution and version to your question.

Comment: Add line where you assign string to variable $LOGFILE.

Comment: That double/single quotes thing is just how bash displays it's "debug" information. Try `set -x` in your own shell and see how bash interprets things.

Comment: Check that your script does not have `\r\n` line endings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Quotation marks**

Per comment from @glenn-jackman, Jenkins is not doing anything with your quotation marks, such as changing double to single - you are seeing the output of `set -x`.  Try this in your shell:

```
set -x
ls "some string with spaces"
```

Output will be something like:

```
+ ls --color=auto 'some string with spaces'
```

`bash` is just showing you debug output of its interpretation and tokenization of your command.

**Ambiguous redirect**

Your `PROJECT_NAME` variable is assigned to a string containing spaces.  You should double-quote the right-hand-side of this expression.

Comment: However I was able to move on from this error by surrounding the LOGFILE variable with double-quotes wherever it existed in my script.